# Extracting data from a dynamic table to another table

Tags: microsoft-excel

Edited version:

I have a large set of data in three columns with Type, Value and Count as you can see in the image. I want to extract values and their corresponding counts according to their type and group them separately. As you can see in the image in columns F:G and I:J. The type and values don't change but the counts grow in time. Also this is just a simple set of data.I would be glad if someone could give me a suggestion to do this task. Thanks. (It would be great to have "Counts"  listed from Largest to Smallest, if possible).

[image]

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but an Excel guru can probably answer it with the extra information you have provided.

Comment: Is a temporary change ok, see the data one way and then flip back.  First, select A1,B1,C1  and then **Data** on the menu bar, and then **Auto Filter**.  Hit drop down A1, uncheck **All** and only check A.  Then hit drop down for B and C and change sorting.  Want to see "type B", A1 drop down check B, uncheck A and hit ok

Comment: Thank you. But I need a formula, because there is a long list of data and they will be updated. and if I do it that way, it will take a lot of time every time i do it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for a pivot table. On the ribbon bar click Insert and then Pivot Table, select the columns you wish to use as your range. Once created, in the field list menu on the right, drag Type and Value to the Row Labels area and Count to the Values area. Change the value field settings for count (in values box) to Summarize value fields by Sum. When the data updates just right click anywhere on the pivot table and click refresh.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but pivot table is not suitable in my case.

Comment: May I ask why? If it's a formatting issue you can use getpivotadata or vlookup on the pivot table to create a 3rd table. Outside of using a pivot table, you are looking at an extremely large code if there are more than 2-3 values.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. But the issue in my hand is a little more complicated then the example in the question. It is just a part of it.